# Bokeh package in Python: How to use rgb to color option

Tags: python, bokeh

Lets say I have the following code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
p= figure(title = 'title',x_axis_label='x',y_axis_label='y')
p.circle(-25,25, radius=5, color="black", alpha=0.8)
show(p)
```

I am trying to find in documentation how to store `color` with rgb values but cant find it. What I mean something like the following:

```
p.circle(-25,25, radius=5, color=[0,0,0], alpha=0.8)
```

Is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bokeh` supports color entry using multiple methods:

- Named colors (like `green` or `blue`)
- RGB hex values like `#FF3311`
- 3-tuple signifying RGB values like `(0, 0, 0)`
- 4-tuple signifying RGB-Alpha values like `(0, 0, 0, 0.0)`

So for you, you could call your function like this:

```
p.circle(-25, 25, radius=5, color=(0, 0, 0), alpha=0.8)
```

This behavior is defined in the [**Styling - Specifying Colors**](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#specifying-colors) section of `bokeh` documentation.

---

I have sample code here which demonstrates this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

# output to static HTML file
output_file("circle.html", title="circles")

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels, and axis ranges
p = figure(title="circles!", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y',
           y_range=[-50, 50], x_range=[-50, 50])

# add a circle renderer with color options
p.circle(-25, 25, radius=5, color=(0,0,0), alpha=0.8)
p.circle(-10, 5, radius=5, color=(120, 240, 255))

# show the results
show(p)
```

It generates a plot that looks like this:
[image: example circle plot]

Your code above, when I run this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("circle.html")
p= figure(title = 'title',x_axis_label='x',y_axis_label='y')
p.circle(-25,25, radius=5, color="black", alpha=0.8)
show(p)
```

Generates this:

[image: Circle from OP post]

Comment: Do you mean `color=(0, 0, 0)`? :)

Comment: @dpwilson oh whoops! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I have tried that and the result is a white circle. Shouldn't be black? The same behaviour is observed even if i enter invalid values such as `color=(300,34343,2)`

Comment: @MpizosDimitris - I'm not sure what might be causing it for you, I'm running bokeh 0.9.3 and the code I just edited into my post works for me. Also, yours generates a translucent black circle for me.

Comment: I guess is my version. I got the `bokeh==0.9.0` . Thanks for your time.